# Codeigniter error, file doesn't exist

Tags: php, codeigniter

http://mysite/products/create

```
Not Found

The requested URL /products/create was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Server at site5.example.com Port 80
```

From server error =>

```
[Sun Aug 28 23:51:45 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/CodeIgniter_2.0.2/products
```

routes.php =>

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'products';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

What would i do ?

Why is this error ?

In .htaccess file of CodeIgniter_2.0.2 =>

```
Deny from all
```

virtual host for codeigniter =>

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName mysite.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/CodeIgniter_2.0.2

    <Directory /var/www/CodeIgniter_2.0.2>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have a `.htaccess` rewrite the correct URL should be http://yoursite.com/index.php/products. Notice the inclusion of the index.php and the proper domain.

Comment: What do you mean by .htaccess rewrite ? I have edited the original question post. See that.

Answer (score 0):

My virtual Host Configuration:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName mysite.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/CodeIgniter_2.0.2

        <Directory /var/www/CodeIgniter_2.0.2>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
```

And my file .htaccess :

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>                                                                                                                           
       RewriteEngine On                                                                                                                               
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^IP$ [NC]                                                                                                     
       RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f                                                                                                            
       RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d                                                                                                            
      RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|images|js|robots\.txt)                                                                                         
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]                                                                                                          
   </ifModule>                                                                                                                                        
   <ifModule !mod_rewrite.c>                                                                                                                          
      ErrorDocument 404 /IP/CodeIgniter_2.0.2/index.php                                                                                        
  </ifModule>
```

It works great!! :)